# Broken line in excel pivot chart

Tags: excel, ms-office, pivot-table

I have a pivot chart that has lines on it that are being cut off/broken.

I am assuming this is because the "9" field doesn't have any data.  How can I force this line to continue though?

[image: Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this error by:

- Clicking in the pivot chart
- On the design tab, choose "Select Data"
- Select "Hidden and Empty Cells"
- Choose "Connect data points with line"
- Hit "OK"